# Finding V(l) for t>0 in RL circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

One of my problems asks me to find the voltage at time greater than zero. The first part of the question asked me to find current. I was able to solve that part and found it using the general solution for step response of RC: i(l):5+15e^(-1000t) Amps t>0.

the back of the book tells me thing: note the 10 is the resistor

vo = 10(io) + Ldio/dt
= 10(5 + 15e−1000t) + 0.04(−1000)(15e−1000t)
= 50 + 150e−1000t − 600e−1000t
vo = 50 − 450e−1000t V, t  0+

Can anyone explain why? I understand that V(l)=L di/dt and ohms law but why to I do both to find voltage at time greater than zero.

thank you.

Comment: using ...KVL..adding R and L voltages..

Comment: that makes perfect sense. I knew it was something simple like that. I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In these solution i have shown  RL and RC Transient Responses,We saw that the currents and voltages in RL and RC circuits decay exponentially with time, with a characteristic time constant t, **when an applied current or voltage is suddenly removed**.
In general, **when an applied current or voltage suddenly changes, the voltages and currents in an RL or RC** circuit will change exponentially with time, from their initial values to their final values, with the characteristic time constant t.
[image]

[image]

i hope it helps you.